# Slim DI container

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection, slim

My Slim 3 application index structure is:

```
// Instantiate the app
$config = require __DIR__ . '/../src/config.php';
$app = new \Slim\App($config);

// Set up dependencies
require __DIR__ . '/../src/dependencies.php';

// Register middleware
require __DIR__ . '/../src/middleware.php';

// Register routes
require __DIR__ . '/../src/routes.php';

// Run app
$app->run();
```

I have separate worker.php file which is executed through bash script and  this file running non-stop in background ( listens for some events).

How can I inject services in my worker.php file which is not part of Slim app or $container from dependencies.php , for example i want to use Monolog logger.
dependencies:

```
$container = $app->getContainer();

/**@var \App\model\Model access to Model methods */
$model = new \App\model\Loan($app->getContainer()->get('settings')['db']);

$container['logger'] = function ($c) {
    $settings = $c->get('settings')['logger'];
    $logger = new Monolog\Logger($settings['name']);
    $logger->pushProcessor(new Monolog\Processor\UidProcessor());
    $logger->pushHandler(new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler($settings['path'], Monolog\Logger::DEBUG));
    return $logger;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to use the same DI Container in your worker.php

Reference:
https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/Container.php

```
$config = require __DIR__ . '/../src/config.php';
$container = new \Slim\Container($config);
require __DIR__ . '/../src/dependencies.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

You Settings

```
return [
    'settings' => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => true, 
        // 'addContentLengthHeader' => false, // Allow the web server to send the content-length header

        // Monolog settings
        'logger' => [
            'name' => 'slim-app',
            'path' => __DIR__ . '/../logs/app.log',
            'level' => \Monolog\Logger::DEBUG,
        ],

    ],
];
```

in you dependenices.

```
$container['logger'] = function ($c) {
    $settings = $c->get('settings')['logger'];
    $logger = new Monolog\Logger($settings['name']);
    $logger->pushProcessor(new Monolog\Processor\UidProcessor());
    $logger->pushHandler(new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler($settings['path'], Monolog\Logger::DEBUG));
    return $logger;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with [Monolog-Cascade](https://github.com/theorchard/monolog-cascade) as followed:

In dependencies:

```
// Configure Monolog with Cascade
$container['logger'] = function ($c) {
    Cascade::loadConfigFromArray($c->get('settings')['loggerConfig']);
    return Cascade::logger('logger_name_here');
};
```

Then in your config file (example with 2 handlers):

```
// Monolog-Cascade settings
    'loggerConfig' => [
        'handlers' => [
            // Stdout handler
            'console' => [
                'class' => 'Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler',
                'stream' => 'php://stdout',
                'level' => 'DEBUG'
            ],
            // File handler
            'file' => [
                'class' => 'Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler',
                'stream' => __DIR__.'/../../logs/hello.log',
                'level' => 'INFO'
            ]
        ],
        'loggers' => [
            'logger_name_here' => [
                'handlers' => ['console', 'file']
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

You can add as many loggers, handlers, formatters, processors, etc. as you want in the config. Cascade will set up everything for you.

[Disclaimer]: I'm the main contributor of [Monolog-Cascade](https://github.com/theorchard/monolog-cascade)